# AWS site down after instance reboot

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have run the below command to change the timezone in server.

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Kolkata /etc/localtime
sudo reboot
```

before running this command I have try to create `/etc/sysconfig/clock` file adding a `zone="Asia/Kolkata"` in it but I am getting error while saving the file as **"permission denied"**

So I run the above command.but after rebooting instance when I try to open my site [mcook.co.in](http://www.mcook.co.in) it shows me error **"No data received"**.

I have check my public ip changed or not but its not changed as I am using Elastic IP.

I am not much familiar with AWS but after rebooting instance this issues are occurs.

```
netstate -ntlp
```

output :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 172.31.33.144:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:20000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:995             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:110             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::53                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::995                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::110                  :::*                    LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

Comment: The correct message is "Connection refused", can you access it via SSH?

Comment: yes I can access it via SSH

Comment: @Yaron : yes I can also connect via FTP to that ip

Comment: Run `netstat -ntlup`, check to see what process is using the port you are trying to access.

Comment: @Yaron I have edit my question with `netstat -ntlp` output.

Comment: There's nothing listening on port 80, it's not surprising that you're getting this error, you should run the service or make it load on startup.

Comment: which service i need to run I mean do I need to start apache server again ? or any other command ?

Comment: Probably starting the Apache server should fix the issue.

Comment: @Yaron : I try to restart the server but still same error no process on running on port 80.

Comment: Can you send the error message? Do you want to move over to the chat?

Comment: I mean server restart successfully but the same error while opening site. sorry I can't chat now..

Comment: Try running netstat command again and see if something is listening on port 80, if it doesn't respond the service is failing.

Comment: ya after restarting command I have try the netstate still it not listen any process.

Comment: If nothing is listening on this port that explains why you are not getting any response, try to fix your httpd/apache/nginx first.

Comment: @Yaron : I have check the apache error log which is like this `[Wed Jul 27 22:59:36.251147 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1760] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) SVN/1.8.8 mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17 OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations`

Comment: So it is running normally with no errors? Are you sure? Can you try `curl localhost`?